# No match on document if the search string is longer than the search field

Tags: elasticsearch, synonym, elasticsearch-query, elasticsearch-analyzers

I have a title I am looking for

The title is, and is stored in a document as 
"Police diaries : stefan zweig"

When I search "Police"
I get the result. 
But when I search Policeman
I do not get the result.

Here is the query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "fields": [
              "title",
              omitted because irrelevance...
            ],
            "query": "Policeman",
            "fuzziness": "1.5",
            "prefix_length": "2"
          }
        }
      ],
      "must": {
        omitted because irrelevance...
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "_score": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

and here is the mapping

```
{
    "books": {
        "mappings": {
            "book": {
                "_all": {
                    "analyzer": "nGram_analyzer", 
                    "search_analyzer": "whitespace_analyzer"
                },
                "properties": {
                    "title": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "raw": {
                                "type": "keyword"
                            },
                            "sort": {
                                "type": "text",
                                "analyzer": "to order in another language, (creates a string with symbols)",
                                "fielddata": true
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It should be noted that I have documents with a title  "some title"
which get hits if I search for "someone title".

I cant figure out why the police book is not showing up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have 2 parts of your question.

1. You want to search the title containing `police` when searching for `policeman`.
2. want to know why `some title` documents match the `someone title` document and according to that you expect the first one to match as well.

Let me first explain you **why second query matches and the why the first one doesn't and then would tell you, how to make the first one to work.**

Your document containing `some title` creates below tokens and you can verify this with [analyzer API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html).

```
POST /_analyze

{
    "text": "some title",
    "analyzer" : "standard" --> default analyzer for text field
}
```

### Generated tokens

```
{
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "some",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 4,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 0
        },
        {
            "token": "title",
            "start_offset": 5,
            "end_offset": 10,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

Now when you search for `someone title` using the [match query which is analyzed](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html) and uses the same analyzer which is used on `index time` on field.

So it creates 2 tokens `someone` and `title` and match query matches the `title` tokens, which is the reason it comes in your search result, you can also use [Explain API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-explain.html) to verify and see the internals how it matches in detail.

### How to bring `police` title when searching for `policeman`

You need to make use of [synonyms token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-synonym-tokenfilter.html) as shown in the below example.

### Index Def

```
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "synonyms": {
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase",
                        "synonym_filter"
                    ],
                    "tokenizer": "standard"
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "synonym_filter": {
                    "type": "synonym",
                    "synonyms" : ["policeman => police"] --> note this
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "synonyms"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Index sample doc

```
{
  "dialog" : "police"
}
```

### Search query having term `policeman`

```
{
    "query": {
        "match" : {
            "dialog" : {
                "query" : "policeman"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### And search result

```
 "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "so_syn",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.2876821,
        "_source": {
          "dialog": "police" --> note source has `police` only.
        }
      }
    ]
```